# twitter4j Stop working suddenly

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I have implemented fetching data from twitter using twitter4j (twitter4j.3.0.3.jar).
The data suddenly stopped coming since 10 Dec, 2013 and I have made no changes in the code.
When I debugged using logger it gives exception .I have used the following in catch block to print the exception:

```
logger.info("twitter exception catched "+te);
logger.info("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
```

===>>>The exception caught is something like this

```
13:32:25,042 INFO  [TwitterIntegrationHelper] twitter exception catched api.twitter.com
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=d35baff5 or
        http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=13208874
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[d35baff5-13208874 43208640-50f081d2], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.4-SNAPSHOT}
13:32:25,043 INFO  [TwitterIntegrationHelper] Failed to search tweets: api.twitter.com
```

===>>>

Along with this twitter has changed its certification  which is effective from 10th December, 2013. How can I ensure if i have same certification in the JBOSS server.

I also try to use to use twitter4j.3.0.5.jar which is also not working.
I use twitter4j.properties method to authentication.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

One reason that you (and we) are having problems diagnosing this is that you are logging the exception the wrong way:

```
    logger.info("twitter exception catched "+te);
```

This is calling `toString` on the exception object and appending that to the message.

What you *should* do is to pass the exception object as a parameter in the logger call; e.g.

```
    // slf4j, log4j or logback
    logger.info("twitter exception caught", te);   

    // java.util.logging
    logger.log(Level,INFO, "twitter exception caught", te);
```

If you do this, you should see the stacktrace in the logs, and that will help you / us figure out what the root cause is.

---

Re the Twitter SSL Certificate change, according to [this posting](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter4j/sLLS-jbH0DE), you should be OK for a range of platforms.  But the fact that the certification changed and your system stopped working *on the same day* is stong hint that the two events are related.

Answer (score 0):

Update security certificate and it will work fine.